# access checkbox populated in treeview

Tags: treeview

I am populating a treelist in the run-time. I want to add a checkbox to every leaf of the treelist. I am using the function below to populate the treeview and it works fine. but I am not able to access the checkbox 
here is my code

```
Private Function GetChilds(ParentID As Integer) As String
    Dim ChildsStr As String = ""
    SQL = "Select Category_Name,Category_ID from Categories where Category_IsDeleted=0 and Category_ParentID=" & ParentID & " order by Category_Order"
    Dim drx As SqlDataReader
    drx = PF.ExecuteReader(SQL)
    If drx.HasRows Then
        ChildsStr += "<ul style='display: block'>" & vbNewLine
        Do While drx.Read
            Dim Ishavechd As Boolean = IsHaveChild(drx("Category_ID"))
            If Ishavechd Then
                ChildsStr += "<li class=""file-tree-folder open"">" & vbNewLine
            Else

                ChildsStr += "<li>" & vbNewLine
            End If
            ChildsStr += drx("Category_Name") & "&nbsp;&nbsp;"
            If Not Ishavechd Then ChildsStr += " <input id='" & drx("Category_ID") & "'  type='checkbox' />"
            ChildsStr += GetChilds(drx("Category_ID"))
            ChildsStr += "</li>" & vbNewLine
        Loop
        ChildsStr += "</ul>" & vbNewLine

    End If
    drx.Close()
    Return ChildsStr
End Function
```

it populates good. and I am using this code to retrieve the checkbox value

```
Dim chk As  HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox = CType(Panel1.FindControl("8"), HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox)
    Response.Write(chk.Checked)
```

There is a checkbox with this id "8" I am sure of that.

I am adding the treeview to panel

```
  <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
```

I am getting this error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Please help.

Comment: In what event do you append to reach it? Also, how did you acquire surety about 8 being the correct id?

Comment: I call that function to populate the treeview in page_load event. 8 is one of the category_ID field that i am using as id for the checkbox and I have viewed the page source to be sure of that

Comment: Even if you are absolutely sure that you identify the id correctly, this approach is messy. So it will cause you problems in the future if it does not already cause some problems. Maaybe you would want to make a data member for that checkbox somewhere to avoid relying on a hard-coded id.

Comment: That is only for testing purpose. In real time I am going to use array with the ids from the database. I am just trying to make it work with single checkbox and them will apply the real time approach. what do you mean by "make a data member for checkbox"?

Comment: Data members are attributes of objects. If you could refer it via Me.myCheckBox, then you would not have to worry about identifiers. You would initialize like this and later on you would be able to reuse it.

Comment: Could you give me an example? Thank you

Comment: Sure. Take a look at page 225 of the book titled Professional Web Parts and Custom Controls with ASP.NET 2.0 by Peter Vogel (https://books.google.ro/books?id=du0wDsIFoRAC&pg=PA225&lpg=PA225&dq=vb.net+%22Me.myControl%22&source=bl&ots=x0W69c-Fg4&sig=ACfU3U2vPLKzk32CF7IuHgTDMA_CaWxQKg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjcn5_RvrjoAhViw4sKHR8fDl4Q6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=vb.net%20%22Me.myControl%22&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I have added name attribute to the checkbox

```
<input name='" & drx("Category_ID") & "' id='" & drx("Category_ID") & "'  type='checkbox' />
```

in the button click I used

```
Reques.form(checkbox name)
```